# how to create a mesh whose faces reduces to zero as approaching towards center?

Tags: modeling, particles, bezier-curves

hello blender community ..
please assist me making this pattern. I tried all the ways but failed to achive the similar one shown in image. I have idea that particle system might be used at vertices but how to make such mesh whose vertices approaches to  zero while moving towards center . [image]

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the Array modifier

1. Starty with a cylinder and a *Bezier Circle*
2. Add an *Array Modifier > Fit Length* and target the Bezier
3. Add a *Curve modifier* and target the Bezier

<sub>Changing the Bezier diameter changes the number of bristles. You can also include vertex instancing etc...</sub>

[image]

Comment: thank you . one more thing how I will duplicate it  towards center. keep in mind beizer is not perfect circle it is random shaped and we have to duplicate and scale it at even distance from boundaries ...

Comment: Well, you can simply eyeball it :). When looking at the reference photo, the gaps aren't perfectly evenly spaced :).

Comment: irrespective of the photo is there any way to evenly space such a mesh ? any tool ? rather duplicating and scaling every one independently which is definitely a waste of time. thanks in advance jachym

Comment: Hey :). I noticed you asked a new question for that, so I [posted an answer there](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/206745/78972).