# how to duplicate and scale loop mesh with even offset

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

How do I use the *Array* modifier for internal loops having constant offset at boundaries. in this figure every duplicated curve is not at equal distance from the previous one.

[image]

Comment: If I understand well, the image above is what you **don't** want?

Comment: It isn't possible to get even spacing between these curves by scaling alone since they don't have radial symmetry, but you can get a set of curves equidistant from each other by using tools other than the Array modifier.

Comment: yes can you please mention what these tools are ?? I need equal spacing in between non radial curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Loopcuts for precise spacing.

1. Inset your shape
2. Add as many loopcuts as you need
3. Remove unnecessary edges

You can split the end result into different objects, convert to curves, etc... :)

[image]

Comment: thank you jachym Michal it is the most omtiaml solution in by case. stay blessed and happy new year

Comment: Happy new year to you too :)